# Claims Authentication -- SharePoint FBA random user error

Tags: sharepoint-2010, forms-authentication

I am working on custom Forms page which is working absolutely fine.When a user sign up
his account details are
Account Name i:0#.f|CustomMembership|100089
Name 100089
Which is expected.But for random users when they try to login again it throws error and replaces as below
Account Name i:0#.f|CustomMembership|100089
Name i:0#.f|CustomMembership|100089

Could not understand why?
Can any one help me out on this please.

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not invalidating your cookies when you logout.

How are you loging out?

As a test to check if this is the problem when you log out clear the cookies and try to login anc see if that happens.